# Js if is not work in setInterval()

Tags: function, if-statement, setinterval, js-cookie

## Hello!

I have This in my website:

```
  var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
  if (!sKey) { return null; }
  return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
 },
 setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
 if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) {return false; }
var sExpires = "";
if (vEnd) {
  switch (vEnd.constructor) {
    case Number:
      sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
      break;
    case String:
      sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
      break;
    case Date:
      sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
      break;
  }
}
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
return true;
},
removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
return true;
},
hasItem: function (sKey) {
if (!sKey) { return false; }
return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
},
keys: function () {
var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
return aKeys;
}
};

alert('In next prompt enter "admin".')

var admin = prompt('Name?')

docCookies.setItem('name',admin);

setInterval(function() {if (docCookies.getItem('name')){}else{var a = 2}}, 1000)
```

But this is not work:

```
setInterval(function() {if (docCookies.getItem('name')){}else{var a = 2}}, 1000)
```

Why thi is not work:

```
setInterval(function() {if (docCookies.getItem('name')){}else{var a = 2}}, 1000)
```

What in page not work and why?
I

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return false; }
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};

alert('In next prompt enter "admin".')

var admin = prompt('Name?')

docCookies.setItem('name',admin);

setInterval(function() {if (docCookies.getItem('name')){}else{var a = 2}}, 1000)
```

Comment: How have you determined that the code doesn't work, and what does that mean exactly? What happens when you try to run the code? The code that you indicate is not working doesn't affect anything else, why do you think that it's not working?

Comment: @Guffa
I want if in site haven't cookie with name "name" var a = 2, but while i delete cookie in console and enter "a" to see whether а = 2 --> console result is "a is not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is declared locally in the function, so it only exists inside that scope, and only while the function is running.

Declare the variable in the global scope, so that you can set it and read it anywhere:

```
var a;

setInterval(function() {
  if (!docCookies.getItem('name')) {
    a = 2;
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i know this. I realized this from my friend.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.